# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'get_default_graph'

Tags: tensorflow

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

model = Sequential([    Dense(32, activation='relu', input_shape=(5038,)),    Dense(32, activation='relu'),    Dense(881, activation='sigmoid'),])
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
hist = model.fit(X_train, Y_train,          batch_size=32, epochs=100,          validation_data=(X_val, Y_val))
```

Gives the following OUtput

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in _get_default_graph()
     65     try:
---> 66         return tf.get_default_graph()
     67     except AttributeError:

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'get_default_graph'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in _get_default_graph()
     67     except AttributeError:
     68         raise RuntimeError(
---> 69             'It looks like you are trying to use '
     70             'a version of multi-backend Keras that '
     71             'does not support TensorFlow 2.0. We recommend '

RuntimeError: It looks like you are trying to use a version of multi-backend Keras that does not support TensorFlow 2.0. We recommend using `tf.keras`, or alternatively, downgrading to TensorFlow 1.14.
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using TensorFlow 2.0 (or a more recent version). TensorFlow >= 2.0 has full, built-in support for Keras, under `tf.keras`. As documented at the [Keras website](https://keras.io/), TensorFlow users should use `tf.keras` instead of the Keras module.

Your specific example can be rewritten using `tf.keras` in the following way:

```
import tensorflow as tf


model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu', input_shape=(5038,)), 
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(881, activation='sigmoid')])
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
hist = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=100, validation_data=(X_val, Y_val))
```

For more information, see the tf.keras tutorials here: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials